# forward checking and contraint propagation

Tags: algorithm

I want to implement n-queen problem by constraint propagation way.What are differences between forward checking and constraint propagation in n-queens problem?

Comment: you might have better luck at cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Forward checking propagates information from assigned to unassigned variables, but does not provide early detection for all failures.

Constraint propagation iteratedly enforces constraints locally.